# Grails - Maven - STS

Tags: grails, maven, build, dependencies, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am relatively new to this and still bit puzzled how the Maven dependencies (in *pom.xml*) and the Grails dependencies (in *BuildConfig.groovy*) hang together.

When I choose *Convert to Grails Project...* in STS (Springsource Tool Suite) it seems to list the different (i.e. the Grails) dependencies.

Do I have to keep them in synch if I wanna receive a WAR file with *mvn package/install*?  Sometimes I get weird build error and I am always unsure where to look for a fix.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a mavenized grails project.  See this bug report:
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-596

When working with a mavenized grails dependency you can work with a grails project, but make sure to turn off dependency management from right-click -> Grails Tools -> Disable Dependency Management.

There is not much tooling support for these projects since the STS grails tooling relies on calling grails to determine project structure and dependencies.  But, when using maven, grails is not called directly and the Grails tooling is not initialized.